# Edit placeholders in Outlook Template File (.oft)

Tags: vba, outlook

I have created an Outlook template, and written a macro to open the template file as a new email ready to send.

```vba
Sub Governance_Email()
    Dim UserName, ReportName, msg_1, msg_2, Title, Default

    Default = "1"
    Title = "Email Form"
    msg_1 = "Enter User"
    msg_2 = "Enter Report Name"

    UserName = InputBox(msg_1, Title, Default)
    ReportName = InputBox(msg_2, Title, Default)

    Set msg = Application.CreateItemFromTemplate("<path_to_file>\template_addDescription.oft")
    msg.Display
End Sub
```

The fields I am trying to change are marked by the placeholders `[NAME]` and `[REPORT]`, and are captured in the variables `UserName` and `ReportName`.

Email Screenshot:
[image: Email Screenshot]

How do I edit the placeholders in the generated email?

Comment: You are currently recreating the "Mail Merge to Outlook" feature that already exists in MS Word. Maybe you want to check this out and use it instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `HTMLBody` property of the `MailItem` class to get the message body where you can replace everything you need. If you use plain text messages consider using the `Body` property.

```
Sub VBA_Replace_Function()

    Dim sString As String, sSubString As String

    sString = "hi [NAME]"

    sSubString = Replace(sString, "[NAME]", "Eugene")

    MsgBox "Replace F1 with Help :" & sSubString, vbInformation, "VBA Replace Function"

End Sub
```

See [Overview of VBA Replace Function](https://vbaf1.com/functions/replace/) for more information.

Also, you may consider using the Word object model which provides the `Replace` method out of the box.

---

The Outlook object model provides three main ways for working with item bodies:

1. [Body](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff865304(v=office.15).aspx) -  a string representing the clear-text body of the Outlook item.
2. [HTMLBody](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868941(v=office.15).aspx) - a string representing the HTML body of the specified item.
3. [Word editor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868196(v=office.15).aspx) - the Microsoft Word Document Object Model of the message being displayed. The WordEditor property of the Inspector class returns an instance of the Document class from the Word object model which you can use to set up the message body.

You can read more about all these ways in the [Chapter 17: Working with Item Bodies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492012%28v=office.12%29.aspx). It is up to you which way is to choose to deal with the message body. But the Word object model provides all the required methods to get the job done.